# Getting Label's Text From Static Method

Tags: c#, text, static, label

I'm trying to take label1.Text
how can i do it from static method
(Windows Form)

```
public static IntPtr hookProc(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{         
    if (code >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYUP)
    {
        int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);

        if (vkCode.ToString() == "117") //F6
        {                    
            MessageBox.Show(**label1.Text**)
        }

    return (IntPtr)1;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Static Methods and ability to access variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28846320/static-methods-and-ability-to-access-variables)

Comment: What is `label1`, please? WinForms, WPF?

Comment: `MessageBox.Show(Application.OpenForms.OfType<MyForm>().Last()?.Label1?.Text);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you use *WinForms* and `label1` is `Label` control on `MyForm` you have to find the (right) *instance* of `MyForm` (which `label1` should we use if we have, say, three opened `MyForm` instances?):

```
 using System.Linq;
 ...

 MessageBox.Show(Application
   .OpenForms
   .OfType<MyForm>()
   .Last()
  ?.label1
  ?.Text ?? "Some Default Value");
```

Here we use the *last* opened instance of `MyForm` and if it exists get `label1`; please, note that either `label1` must be *accessible* from `hookProc`, i.e. `hookProc` is implemented within `MyForm` or `label1` is declared as `public`.

Comment: @SbekS: if the problem has been solved, please, either provide your solution (for other people can see and use it) or mark an answer (that's provided the solution) as *accepted*

Answer (score 0):

Static methods and properties cannot access non-static fields and events in their containing type, and they cannot access an instance variable of any object unless it is explicitly passed in a method parameter.

Assuming label1 is instance variable, you should pass its text as 1 of parameters to your function

```
public static IntPtr hookProc(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, string labelText)
```